# Solve equations for multiple variables at same time

Tags: equation-solving, algebra

Here is an example equation:

```
Solve[{a*x + b*y == c}, {a}]
```

It gives me:

```
a -> (c - b*y)/x
```

To solve the same equation for `b`, I need to write:

```
Solve[{a*x + b*y == c}, {b}]
```

It will give me:

```
b -> (c - a*x)/y
```

Similarly, I will have to repeat the steps for all variables like `x` and `y`. Is there an easier to tell Mathematica to solve an equation for all variables one by one?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like: Solve[{a*x + b*y == c}, {#}][[1]] & /@ {a, b, c} &

Comment: `Flatten@Table[ Solve[a x + b y == c, {z}],  {z, {a, b, c, x, y}}]`   is an easy-to-read method that uses two of the most basic list manipulation functions.

Comment: Thank you very much @LouisB. Is this feature mentioned somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: @RealNoob: you might like to peruse these learning references: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice

Comment: Thanks @Moo. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing the solution provided by LouisB

```
Clear["Global`*"]

solve[eqn_Equal] := Module[
  {$z, vars = Variables[Level[eqn, {-1}]]},
  Table[Solve[eqn, {$z}][[1]], {$z, vars}]]

eqn = a x + b y == c;

sol = solve[eqn]

(* {{a -> (c - b y)/x}, {b -> (c - a x)/y}, {c -> a x + b y}, {x -> (c - b y)/
   a}, {y -> (c - a x)/b}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions

```
And @@ (eqn /. sol)

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bob. Could you please provide links to some resources where I can learn more about using Mathemtica in such an advanced manner? I am an absolute beginner in Mathemtica and it seems to be a very powerful tool. :)

Comment: All the links are built into Mathematica. Highlight any function or operator and click `F1` for help. On the documentation paqes look at the examples and look for the links to `Tutorials` and `Related Guides`.